# How to setup MySQL on MacOS (Getting Started)

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have been running all my apps with Rails and PostgreSQL, which was very easy to setup using `brew install postgresql` and `brew services start postgresql`. With MySQL is proving to be a very big pain.

**How do I setup MySQL from 0 and clean up all the mess I made?**

I have downloaded MySQL Community Server 8.0.21 on my MacOS and registered a root password during the setup.

After that I have run the folowing commands that render the following errors.

```
$ mysql -u root -p

# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)
```

```
$ mysql.server start

# Starting MySQL
# ./usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.21_1/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/Victors-MBP.err: Permission denied
# /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.21_1/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/Victors-MBP.err: Permission denied
# /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.21_1/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199: /usr/local/var/mysql/Victors-MBP.err: Permission denied
# /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.21_1/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/Victors-MBP.err: Permission denied
# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid).
```

```
$ brew doctor
$ brew uninstall mysql
$ brew cleanup
$ brew install mysql

# The whole setup works, but every attempt to run the server still renders the same errors.
```

```
$ mysql_secure_installation 

# after inputting the correct root password...

# Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)
```

Please help. I have tried many more different setups and corrections, none of which have worked.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: https://superuser.com/a/603027/1220403

Basically execute this command:

```
$ mysql -u root mysql
```

And you'll be able to set a password using ALTER USER and access the mysql command line. Also, you'll be able to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a simple Macintosh installer and a control-panel that goes along with it ... shows up in *"System Preferences."*  Are you sure that the server is actually **running?**  Betcha it ain't.

Comment: Can't get is to start unfortunately. I click that Start the Server button only for it to turn off by itself in 2 seconds...